# Issues with swift map chaining

Tags: swift, maps, reduce

One qq about maps and chaining.
Below code works perfectly fine

```
    var raceResults = [["one","two","four"],["two","one","five","six"],["two","one","four","ten"],["one","two","four"]]

let numberedRaceResults = raceResults
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { outterOffset, raceResult in
        raceResult
            .enumerated()
            .map { innerOffset, element in "\(outterOffset).\(innerOffset). \(element)" }
    }

for numberedResult in numberedRaceResults {
    print(numberedResult)
}
```

But when I add two print statements in it , it stops working.
Can someone-one please help me to understand

1.what's the deal with those print statements
2. If I replace flatmap with map, code below does not work. My understanding about flatmap is it just eliminates the nil values . Is there something on top of it that flatmap does comapred to map which is why I am not getting expected results when I replace flatmap with map ?

```
var raceResults = [["one","two","four"],["two","one","five","six"],["two","one","four","ten"],["one","two","four"]]

let numberedRaceResults = raceResults
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { outterOffset, raceResult in
        print(outterOffset)
        print(raceResult)
        raceResult
            .enumerated()
            .map { innerOffset, element in "\(outterOffset).\(innerOffset). \(element)" }
    }

for numberedResult in numberedRaceResults {
    print(numberedResult)
}
```

Comment: "My understanding about flatmap is it just eliminates the nil values" Are you from the Swift 2 era or something lol? That is a very old and deprecated thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write many lines inside the `{}` of `flatMap` function you need to tell it what should be the result and since `print` returns `() / void` ,hence you get nothing , so you need to add a `return` under the two prints

```
    let numberedRaceResults = raceResults
        .enumerated()
        .flatMap { outterOffset, raceResult in
            print(outterOffset)
            print(raceResult)
            return raceResult // here  
                .enumerated()
                .map { innerOffset, element in "\(outterOffset).\(innerOffset). \(element)" }
        }

    for numberedResult in numberedRaceResults {
        print(numberedResult)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `print` calls were absent, the body of the `flatMap` closure was only *a single expression*, saying `raceResult.enumerated().map { ... }`.

When the body of a closure is a single expression, the closure implicitly *returns* that expression. That is, the closure passed to `flatMap` here actually means `return raceResult.enumerated().map { ... }`.

When you add the `print` calls, the closure is no longer a single expression, and so *doesn't* return the `raceResult.enumerated().map { ... }` expression, and returns `Void` instead. This actually makes it call another (deprecated) [overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/enumeratedsequence/2995490-flatmap) of `flatMap` that "just eliminates the nil values", which we now call `compactMap`.

The overload of [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/enumeratedsequence/2995488-flatmap) that is *intended*, allows you to map elements of an array to another sequence, and *flattens* it. For example, here we are mapping each race result to the array of `raceResult.enumerated().map { ... }`. `flatMap` will then flatten all these string arrays by joining them all together into a single array.

---

Anyway, you can fix the code by explicitly writing the `return`.

```
let numberedRaceResults = raceResults
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { (outterOffset, raceResult) -> [String] in
        print(outterOffset)
        print(raceResult)
        return raceResult
            .enumerated()
            .map { innerOffset, element in "\(outterOffset).\(innerOffset). \(element)" }
    }
```

Note that you also need to specify the return type of the closure now (`[String]`), because Swift cannot infer the type of multi-statement closures very well :(